# what do the interpolationmethods ‘cubicspline’ and ‘from_derivatives’ do?

Tags: python, pandas, parameters, scipy, interpolation

pandas interpolation documentary already leaves helpful notes for all the other Notes on wether they use the actual numerical indices or a timeindex for the interpolation.

```
method str, default ‘linear’

    Interpolation technique to use. One of:

        ‘linear’: Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced. This is the only method supported on MultiIndexes.

        ‘time’: Works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval.

        ‘index’, ‘values’: use the actual numerical values of the index.

        ‘pad’: Fill in NaNs using existing values.

        ‘nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘spline’, ‘barycentric’, ‘polynomial’: Passed to scipy.interpolate.interp1d. These methods use the numerical values of the index. Both ‘polynomial’ and ‘spline’ require that you also specify an order (int), e.g. df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=5).

        ‘krogh’, ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘spline’, ‘pchip’, ‘akima’, ‘cubicspline’: Wrappers around the SciPy interpolation methods of similar names. See Notes.

        ‘from_derivatives’: Refers to scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives which replaces ‘piecewise_polynomial’ interpolation method in scipy 0.18.
```

But unfortunately I couldnt find this information for the two last ones:

```
cubicspline 
and
from_derivatives
```

Answer (score 1):

[scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)

Interpolate data with a piecewise cubic polynomial which is twice continuously differentiable. The result is represented as a PPoly instance with breakpoints matching the given data.

[scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives.html)

Construct a piecewise polynomial in the Bernstein basis, compatible with the specified values and derivatives at breakpoints.